# What is this first name or Haynes surname?

Tags: 18th-century, palaeography, virginia, taxation-records

I need help recognizing this first name for Haynes:
[image]

I think it begins with a `B` perhaps something like `Barimanus`?

This comes from the [Franklin County, Virginia personal tax list for 1786](http://www.binnsgenealogy.com/MembersOnlyArea/pdfs/Franklin/1786Personal/11.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it reads **Parmenus**.

Parmenas is a rare biblical name of Greek origin, referring to one of the seven men appointed to care for the poor of Jerusalem. Specifically, he was mentioned in Acts 6:5:

> And the saying pleased the whole multitude: and they chose Stephen, a
>   man full of faith and of the Holy Ghost, and Philip, and Prochorus,
>   and Nicanor, and Timon, and Parmenas, and Nicolas a proselyte of
>   Antioch:

<sup>–*[Acts 6:5, King James Version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts%206%3A5&version=KJV)*</sup>

A search of any of the major genealogy websites for this name will bring up hundreds of hits, mostly USA records. So while uncommon, certainly not unique.

Comment: "Franklin County, Virginia: A History" by Marshall Wingfield agrees: it has the same 1786 tax list and includes "Haynes, Parmenus" as one entry. Google books [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MGSEOFCOHOQC&lpg=PA206&ots=0vk3hTrdrK&dq=%22parmenus%20haynes%22&pg=PA206#v=onepage&q=%22parmenus%20haynes%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

My previous reading of this first name was incorrect. The other answer is correct. I note that there are a number of refs. listed to this family of which this appears to the earliest:

Parmenas Haynes United States Census, 1850

birth:  1796    Virginia
residence:  1850    Randolph county, Randolph, Alabama, United States
other:  Martha Haynes, Minerva Haynes, Mary E Haynes, Marg H Haynes, Eli** C Haynes, Martha E Haynes...